# Guzzle provide primary and alternative URL in case of Errors

Tags: php, exception, guzzle

Is there a way I can tell guzzle to try a secondary url if the primary url results in a failure.

I now I can try the below:

```
try{
  $body = $client->get('primary_url');
}
catch (ClientException $e | GuzzleException $e | Exception $e){
  $body = $client->get('secondary_url');
}
```

But is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: What does "easier" mean? Create your own function/method to take 2 URLs as argument?

Comment: I mean having it dynamic, eg what if there are 3 routes

Answer (score 0):

You can try code below:

```
function switchUrl($client, $primary_url, $secondary_url) {
    try{
        return $body = $client->get($primary_url);
    } catch (ClientException $e | GuzzleException $e | Exception $e) {
        return $body = $client->get($secondary_url);
    }
}

$result = switchUrl($client, 'primary_url', 'secondary_url');
```

Hope help you.

Comment: What if both fail?

Comment: @TimothyRadier You decide, you asked the question. What if you have 12 URLs and all of the 12 fail?